# Slow refresh due to linker File#getPreLinkedOutput

Tags: javascript, meteor, build, localhost, refresh

My problem is that I have a very long build time after saving changes in my code on localhost. The page refresh lasts for minutes sometimes. I already used `METEOR_PROFILE=100` to identify the problem. Here is the output:

[image]

So, nearly all of the build time depends on `linker File#getPreLinkedOutput` (216,172 ms of 229,823 total).

How can I fix this?

Comment: I remember I read in the past some [github's threads](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284) about long build time with meteor. Which version are you using and which machine?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The reason were (somehow?) related to datatables and pdfMaker. I deleted the files completely and receive them now over CDN. Now it works, except from the pdf export, but I think this is a "new" issue.